# Install conda on Linux automatically

Tags: python, bash, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install conda on Redhat inux. However I want to do it in non interactive way. I wrapped all instructions to install conda in shell file and want to install conda in one shot (viz: sh. conda-install,sh). However when you do manuall there are steps when you have to press Enter couple of time and then it asks for confirmation where is asks yes or no.

How can I do that.

PS: I tried to install using following 
`"yes"|bash anconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh` but it did not work **got stuck in loop.**

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't rpm completely non-interactive? Are you using rpm to install everything?

Comment: Conda isn't installed via an rpm (witness the `anconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh` in the question).

Comment: [chef](https://www.chef.io/) (although [expect](https://core.tcl.tk/expect/index) might be easier given your current approach).

Comment: Is there a RPM available ? @user3483203 can you guide me where it is available?

Answer (score 5):

Ok. i went throught the helper docs of conda and looks like you can install silently by a flag called **b**. So it was as simple like :

```
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b
```